# getting the correct finder selection Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, selection, finder

I´m asking the user of my little project to open a finder window and select one or more objects. Also selecting none is allowed. In this case all items are used.

In my app I check for the first window and try to get the selected items (files or folders)  see **Code1**.
*Please note that some of the variables are global and declared in .h and some are just reset. *

This works fine if the user is not fondeling around in the finder. But he can do several things to trick my app. He can open a finder window e.g. and select a few files. After that he can click on the desktop (the selection in finder window is still there which is correct) and  then select items directly on the desktop. When he returns to my app it recognizes correctly the open window but uses the items from the desktop as selected items which is not what I want. What I want to do, I want the selected items in the frontmost window but I don´t see how I could do it.

Any clues?

**Code1**

```
- (void)applicationWillBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification  {

   [self psProgressWrapper:FALSE :_spinningWheel :spinningWheelText ] ;

   NSUInteger *countArray = 0;
   asResult = @""; //this variable holds the path to the folder the frontmost window belongs to 

   selectionFlag = FALSE; //reset
   allFilesFlag  = FALSE; //reset

      //Get first finder window
    FinderApplication * finder = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.finder" ] ;
    SBElementArray *windows = [finder FinderWindows ] ;

    if([windows count] >0) {
        FinderWindow *theWindow = [windows objectAtIndex:0 ] ;
        asResult = [theWindow name ] ;  //the name of the first window

         //setting a texfield in the GUI to text and color green
      [_errMessage setStringValue:asResult ] ;
      [_errMessage setTextColor: myGreenColor ] ;

      SBElementArray * selection = [[finder selection] get ] ;
      countArray = [selection count ] ;

      if(countArray == 0) {
         atFilesOriginal = (NSMutableArray*) [self checkForSelection:asResult :TRUE ] ;
      }
      else if(countArray > 0) {
         atFilesOriginal = (NSMutableArray*) [selection arrayByApplyingSelector:@selector(name) ] ;
      }
      else {
         asResult = @"NoWin";
      }
   }
   else {
      asResult = @"NoWin";
      [self checkFinderWindowType ] ;
   }

   [self refreshDRPopsWrapper] ;
   [self psProgressFlag:TRUE Wheel:_spinningWheel Text:spinningWheelText];

   [self goConvertBtnWrapper   ] ;
   [self checkFinderWindowType ] ;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

> What I want to do, I want the selected items in the frontmost window
>   but I don´t see how I could do it.

The problem is you are deviating from the established human interface guidelines. Your users will have just as much of a hard time using your app as you are having writing it.

If you want to get file/folder selections, use a NSOpenPanel.

If you do not want a modal window, support drag and drop from the file system. Or use a NSBrowser to help them browse and select files within the window of your application.

If you really want to be operating in Finder, create a Finder plugin.

Comment: Well, my app is a tool which helps the user to rename files or folders in in a finder window. I´m fully aware of GUI guidelines but in this case a modal dialog wouldn´t be very  helpful if the user has a folder with 2000 items e.g. and wants to rename all occurences of Suzanna to Suzi. I hope you see what I mean.

Comment: Added a sentence for your specific use case.

Comment: >>Added a sentence for your specific use case, Sorry, I don´t see what you mean. What did you add?

Comment: You can view history of this answer in an easy to use viewer http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14807893/revisions. You can access this viewer directly from the link next to the word 'edited' as well.

Comment: This answer is really not acceptable. I did not ask for how to do things in the way you think it should be done.